# If only had I known it! / If only I had known it!

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, sentence, subject-verb-inversion

Could you help me, please?

A question for the native speakers (desired) of British English or American English.

Which variant is correct and why? Or it's possible to use either of them)?

If only had I known it!
If only I had known it!

Comment: The second one is correct; the first one isn't, because subject-auxiliary inversion (_had I_ instead of _I had_) is not allowed here. It needs something specific in the context -- a fronted adverb, for instance -- in order to happen, and there's none here.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In the US I *most frequently* hear `"If only I had known"`; when I was home in Britain I also heard a variant construction: `"Had I but known"` which I've *almost never* heard here in the US.

Comment: Thank you very much!